What are methods of parsing complex unstructured text from docx file into pandas?
I have a docx file with unstructured text that looks like the following:
docx File
Prep

Northern Kitchen Number One      K01-24-01-P01     $132,500

Background:

None

Project Description:

Some long project description

List of Deliverables:

#1 - A deliverable.
#2 - Another deliverable.

Others:

None

Cost:

Prep Item #1 & 2 - Some text here.

Criteria:

#1a, 1b, & 2c - Stuff here.
#2 - More stuff here.
#3 - Even more stuff here too.


Southern Kitchen Number Two     K03-24-01-P01    $50,2333

Background:

None

Project Description:

None

List of Deliverables:

#1 - A deliverable.

Others:

None

Cost:

None

Criteria:

#1a, 1b, & 2c - Stuff here.

How would you parse out each line that does not have a none and create a dataframe that look like the following:



Kitchen
Process
Code
Task
Description




Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
Project Description
Some long project description.


Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
List of Deliverables
#1 - A deliverable.


Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
List of Deliverables
#2 - Another deliverable.


Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
Cost
Prep Item #1 & 2 - Some text here.


Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
Criteria
#1a, 1b, & 2c - Stuff here.


Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
Criteria
#2 - More stuff here.


Northern Kitchen Number One
Prep
K01-24-01-P01
Criteria
#3 - Even more stuff here too.


Southern Kitchen Number Two
Prep
K03-24-01-P01
List of Deliverables
#1 - A deliverable.


Southern Kitchen Number Two
Prep
K03-24-01-P01
Criteria
#1a, 1b, & 2c - Stuff here.



At the moment, all I've managed to do is extract the lines from the document and print each line as an entry in a csv file but I'm not really able to manipulate them around into the final dataframe structures I want.  From my research, this would probably require regex and maybe dictionaries?
import docx
import io
import pandas as pd

stuff = '\n'.join([p.text for p in docx.Document(path).paragraphs])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(stuff), on_bad_lines='skip')
df.to_excel('stuff.csv')


It will be difficult to answer this question without a reproducible example of the docx file, with a text representation we can only see the content, not how it is actually formatted

Your question is like: "What are methods of getting unstructured text into a data structure?" Answer: Either knowing keywords which point to/are followed by special data, but then there is a kind of structure,  or guessing and assessing while a training phase. The second is what a AI would do. Thus as @mozway told: There seems to be a structure (Headings, keywords, listings). But to be able to detect that structure, one would need the file and not only the plain text content.

Thank you for the comments, this is my first time using StackOverflow.  I was unsure of how to provide a reproducible example of a docx file so I generalized the question.  I will be trying Lilith's answer and see if I can solve this problem.

the comments are correct that you're not really giving enough information. I think if you can find a regex pattern than matches numbered kitchen lines so that you can separate each section that has a known set of headers you'll be in good shape.
import re

tmp = re.split('\t[0-9]+', junk)  # this pattern works if I assume you have a plain text input
process = tmp[0].strip()
rows = []
for section in tmp[1:]:
    # now you can parse the first line that contains the kitchen and code and turn the remaining header+bullets into a dictionary
    rows.append(some_dict_you extract)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(rows)

btw if you've never used this website I highly recommend it for trying out regex patterns: https://regex101.com/
and here's a post about turning a list of dictionaries into a pandas dataframe: Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame

Thanks for the answer, I was just unsure in general how to proceed with this problem but your answer has given me a direction I can take.
